# is_single() works in plugin, not in theme?

Tags: theme-development

I'm attempting to move some code from a plugin over to my theme's `functions.php` file, but when I attempt to wrap it in the `is_single()` wrapper inside of functions.php, it never fires. What am I missing?

```
if (is_single()) {
    echo "hello world"; 
}
```

I can't get the echo to fire from any inside post page.

This has to be something insanely simple I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that I can think of is to verify that you are in fact on a single post page ( echo out an else conditional, make sure that you are actually hitting your block of code ).

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    echo 'Hello World, Is Single';
} else {
    echo 'Not Single';
}
```

Where exactly are you placing the code (Header, Body, Footer, which template file)?  Are you using any frameworks like Carrington ?

Comment: I'm calling is_single from inside of functions.php. I believe I have to place it inside a function and call the function from an add_action statement.

Comment: For example, this is the only way I can get it to work > add_action('template_redirect', '_my_function');

Comment: Yes, calling it after the template_redirect action is the only way it will work. If the plugin called it directly, it was doing it wrong.

Comment: Just think about where in the script you are calling is_single().  If you add is_single to an an action ( eg template_redirect ) it will be called when that action is fired, make sure that the $wp_query object is available at that point.  
If you call is_single from a function that is on a template that is defined in your functions file you should be fine.